# How to remove GraphQL fields according to other fields, in Gatsby?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, sanity

I have a page query that returns a video playlist. Some videos have 'public' set to true, some false. For the videos that have their public field set to false, I do not want to include the URL of that video in the payload that Gatsby sends to the page because access to those videos is paid for.

Example:

```
export const query = graphql`
    query MyQuery {
        courses: allSanityCourses {
            nodes {
                price
                name
                playlist {
                    title
                    url
                    public
                }
            }
        }
    }
`
```

And the data it returns:

```
[
    {
        "price": 149,
        "name": "Master VS Code",
        "playlist": [
            {
                "title": "Intro",
                "url": "https://youtu.be/qwertyuiop",
                "public": true
            },
            {
                "title": "Principles Part 1",
                "url": "https://youtu.be/poiuytrewq",
                "public": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I prevent Gatsby from sending the second URL (which has public set to false) to the page?

I'm not sure [Query Filters](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/query-filters/) work as they seem to only allow filtering/removing fields based on the content of those same fields. What I need is to filter/remove the URL field based on *another* sibling field "public".

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for:

```
export const query = graphql`
    query MyQuery {
        courses: allSanityCourses(
        filter: {
          playlist: {
            public: { eq: true }
          }
        },
        ){
            nodes {
                price
                name
                playlist {
                    title
                    url
                    public
                }
            }
        }
    }
`
```

The `filter` filter (quite redundant) and the `eq` (equals) option should do the trick for you. Check it in the `localhost:8000/___graphql` playground the tweak/refine it if needed.

You can check for further filters in https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/query-filters/

Comment: I tried it with query MyQuery {
        courses: allSanityCourses(
        filter: {
          playlist: {
      elemMatch: {
       public: { eq: true}
            }
          }
        },
        ){
            nodes {
                price
                title
                playlist {
                    title
                    url
                    public
                }
            }
        }
    }

and it still returns all the playlist elements, public: false included.

Comment: I solved it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68733466/how-to-create-custom-resolvers-for-gatsby-page-queries/68734000#68734000), but if I can do this with GraphQL itself, it would be better.

Comment: Have you tried mine? (eq instead of elemMatch)

Comment: Yeah, sorry I forgot to tell you it resulted in an error: Field "public" is not defined by type "SanityVideoFilterListInput".

Comment: Then you are not filtering for the `allSanityCourses` node